# Error 404--Not Found (while using apache and weblogic)

Tags: apache, jsp, weblogic

I have an application deployed in weblogic, and am using apche server.Normally, when I enter the url for the application, it should display a jsp (1) kind of please wait then this one will redirect to another jsp (2).

the problem is when I enter the url of the application, it displays jsp (1) "please wait" and while redirecting it gives the error (Error 404--Not Found).

What do you think the problem is ?

Comment: What do your weblogic logs show? It's obvious the request hits apache. Can you go to weblogic url directly?

Comment: nothing is displayed , only "server started in running mode

Answer (score 1):

A 404 simply means that the URL is invalid or that the resource actually isn't there where you think it is.

First test its availablility independently with an absolute URL. Such as `http://example.com/context/page.jsp`. If that doesn't work, then verify if the resource is actually there in your webapp where you expect it to be. If that does work, then you likely used a relative URL in the redirect such as:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=/page.jsp">
```

You need to be aware that any relative URL's in the page are relative to the absolute URL of the current request. Thus, if the page was requested with for example `http://example.com/context/wait.jsp`, then the above relative URL will resolve to `http://example.com/page.jsp`. This is thus not going to work if the page is actually located at `http://example.com/context/page.jsp`. You should then replace the URL by the right relative URL:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=page.jsp">
```

or just an absolute URL:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://example.com/context/page.jsp">
```