# multiple war files in single ear with different context roots

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, servlets, weblogic

I have one ear file and two war files
application.xml file is configured like

```
<module id="myeclipse.1312xxxxxxx">
    <web>
      <web-uri>first.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/first</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module id="myeclipse.134xxxxxxxxx">
    <web>
      <web-uri>second.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/second</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
```

when i'm deploying it in local weblogic server it's working fine, but when i deployed it in the server, first.war is working fine but second.war is not. when i tried to access some pages from second.war file like

> "http://host:port/second/somepage.html"

, i'm getting Error 404-Object Not Found Exception.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a classloader issue with the non-local WebLogic server instance you are deploying to since it works on the local deployment.  Try the Classloader Analysis Tool (CAT) to troubleshoot - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13706/classloading.htm#WLPRG495

Comment: if it's class loader issue then will it affect a welcome page(an html page) which is not doing any validation?

Comment: It could, though not necessarily. I'm assuming the WARs deployed without any issue and you can see the context root set properly in the Admin Console for the application?  This thread has some info that might help even if you're not using Apache in front of WebLogic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743541/error-404-not-found-while-using-apache-and-weblogic

Comment: '<Nov 8, 2012 2:46:13 PM EST> <Info> <Deployer> <BEA-149060> <Module /second of application trial successfully transitioned from STATE_ADMIN to STATE_ACTIVE on server .> ' these are the logs in the weblogic server(not local server), but when i'm trying to access the url like http://host:port/second/somepage.html, I'm getting error 404-object not found . But i can access the other war files.